# MongoDB aggregation, Group by value interval,

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

MongoDB documents:

```
[{
  _id: '123213',
  elevation: 2300,
  area: 25
},
{
  _id: '343221',
  elevation: 1600,
  area: 35,
},
{
  _id: '545322',
  elevation: 500
  area: 12,
},
{
  _id: '234234',
  elevation: null,
  area: 5
}]
```

I want to group these on a given interval on elevation and summarize the area property.

- Group 1: < 0
- Group 2: 0 - 1500
- Group 3: 1501 - 3000,
- Group 4: > 3000

So the expected output would be:

```
[{
   interval: '1501-3000',
   count: 2,
   summarizedArea: 60 
},
{
   interval: '0-1500',
   count: 1,
   summarizedArea: 12,
},
{
   interval: 'N/A',
   count: 1,
   summarizedArea: 5
}]
```

If possible, I want to use the `aggregation pipeline`.

Maybe something with `$range`? Or a combination of `$gte` and `$lte`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Feliix suggested [$bucket](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) should do the job, but boundaries should be slightly different to play well with negative and `N/A` values:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $bucket: {
      groupBy: "$elevation",
      boundaries: [ -Number.MAX_VALUE, 0, 1501, 3001, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY ],
      default: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
      output: {
        "count": { $sum: 1 },
        "summarizedArea" : { $sum: "$area" }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

The formatting stage below can be added to the pipeline to adjust shape of the response:

```
  { $group: {
      _id: null,
      documents: { $push: {          
          interval: { $let: {
              vars: {
                  idx: { $switch: {
                      branches: [
                          { case: { $eq: [ "$_id", -Number.MAX_VALUE ] }, then: 3 },
                          { case: { $eq: [ "$_id", 0 ] }, then: 2 },
                          { case: { $eq: [ "$_id", 1501 ] }, then: 1 },
                          { case: { $eq: [ "$_id", 3001 ] }, then: 0 }
                      ],
                      default: 4
                  } }
              },
              in: { $arrayElemAt: [ [ ">3000", "1501-3000", "0-1500", "<0", "N/A" ], "$$idx" ] } 
          } },
          count: "$count",
          summarizedArea: "$summarizedArea"
      } }
  } }
```

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with `_id: null` [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) es all groups into array of a single document.

[$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) maps `$_id` from previous stage to text labels of interval defined in the array `[ ">3000", "1501-3000", "0-1500", "<0", "N/A" ]`. For that it calculates `idx` index of the label using [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/).

It must be way simpler to implement the logic on application level unless you absolutely need to do it in the pipeline.

Comment: Is it possible to make a $project to output it as in question?

Comment: @Per, I am sure its, but could you define "*as in question*" ? Is it interval labels (btw, they look wrong in the question),  a single document with the array instead of a cursor, or specific order of documents?

Comment: Not a single document. An array with each group. With interval-labels. Order is not important.

Comment: @Per Sorry, I didn't get it. It is either a single document with an array of groups: `[{ interval: '1501-3000'...},{interval: '0-1500'....}...]` or a cursor of documents without array at all: `{ interval: '1501-3000'...},{interval: '0-1500'....}...`.

Comment: @Per, also about labels. Would it be fair to assume `elevation` is always integer?

Comment: An array of groups. Yes elevation is always integer or not existing.

Comment: That was messy :) As suggested, I'll do that on application level instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can use `$bucket` introduced in MongoDB 3.4 to achive this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $bucket: {
      groupBy: "$elevation",
      boundaries: [
        0,
        1500,
        3000,
        5000
      ],
      default: 10000,
      output: {
        "count": {
          $sum: 1
        },
        "summarizedArea": {
          $sum: "$area"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "count": 1,
    "summarizedArea": 12
  },
  {
    "_id": 1500,
    "count": 2,
    "summarizedArea": 60
  },
  {
    "_id": 10000,
    "count": 1,
    "summarizedArea": 5
  }
]
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/xFe7ZygMqaY](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xFe7ZygMqaY)